# Why can a Num act like a Fractional?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, function-call, adhoc-polymorphism

As expected, this works fine:

```
foo :: Fractional a => a
foo = undefined                -- datum

bar :: Num a => a -> a
bar a = undefined              -- function

baz :: Fractional a => a
baz = bar foo                  -- application
```

This works as expected because every `Fractional` is also a `Num`.

So as expected, we can pass a `Fractional` argument into a `Num` parameter.

On the other hand, the following works too. I don't understand why.

```
foo :: Fractional a => a -> a
foo a = undefined              -- function

bar :: Num a => a
bar = undefined                -- datum

baz :: Fractional a => a
baz = foo bar                  -- application
```

Works unexpectedly! There *are* `Num`s that are not `Fractionals`.

So why can I pass a `Num` argument into a `Fractional` parameter? Can you explain?

Comment: Possibly related question that you might find interesting: given that `undefined :: a`, why does `undefined :: Num a => a` work? There are certainly `a`s that are not `Num`s.

Comment: One can see that 'every Fractional is also a Num' by running: `Prelude> :info Fractional` which results in: `class Num a => Fractional a where […omitted…]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chi's answer gives a great high-level explanation of what's happening. I thought it might also be fun to give a slightly more low-level (but also more mechanical) way to understand this, so that you might be able to approach other similar problems, turn a crank, and get the right answer. I'm going to talk about types as a sort of protocol between the user of the value of that type and the implementer.

- For `forall a. t`, the caller gets to choose a type, then they continue with protocol `t` (where `a` has been replaced with the caller's choice everywhere in `t`).
- For `Foo a => t`, the caller must provide proof to the implementer that `a` is an instance of `Foo`. Then they continue with protocol `t`.
- For `t1 -> t2`, the caller gets to choose a value of type `t1` (e.g. by running protocol `t1` with the roles of implementer and caller switched). Then they continue with protocol `t2`.
- For any type `t` (that is, at any time), the implementer can cut the protocol short by just producing a value of the appropriate type. If none of the rules above apply (e.g. if we have reached a base type like `Int` or a bare type variable like `a`), the implementer *must* do so.

Now let's give some distinct names to your terms so we can differentiate them:

```
valFrac :: forall a. Fractional a =>      a
valNum  :: forall a. Num        a =>      a
idFrac  :: forall a. Fractional a => a -> a
idNum   :: forall a. Num        a => a -> a
```

We also have two definitions we want to explore:

```
applyIdNum :: forall a. Fractional a => a
applyIdNum = idNum valFrac

applyIdFrac :: forall a. Fractional a => a
applyIdFrac = idFrac valNum
```

Let's talk about `applyIdNum` first. The protocol says:

1. Caller chooses a type `a`.
2. Caller proves it is `Fractional`.
3. Implementer provides a value of type `a`.

The implementation says:

1. Implementer starts the `idNum` protocol as the caller. So, she must:

   1. Choose a type `a`. She quietly makes the same choice as *her* caller did.
   2. Prove that `a` is an instance of `Num`. This is no problem, because she actually knows that `a` is `Fractional`, and this implies `Num`.
   3. Provide a value of type `a`. Here she chooses `valFrac`. To be complete, she must then show that `valFrac` has the type `a`.
2. So the implementer now runs the `valFrac` protocol. She:

   1. Chooses a type `a`. Here she quietly chooses the type that `idNum` is expecting, which happens to coincidentally be the same as the type that her caller chose for `a`.
   2. Prove that `a` is an instance of `Fractional`. She uses the same proof her caller did.
   3. The implementer of `valFrac` then promises to provide a value of type `a`, as needed.

For completeness, here is the analogous discussion for `applyIdFrac`. The protocol says:

1. Caller chooses a type `a`.
2. Caller proves that `a` is `Fractional`.
3. Implementer must provide a value of type `a`.

The implementation says:

1. Implementer will execute the `idFrac` protocol. So, she must:

   1. Choose a type. Here she quietly chooses whatever her caller chose.
   2. Prove that `a` is `Fractional`. She passes on her caller's proof of this.
   3. Choose a value of type `a`. She will execute the `valNum` protocol to do this; and we must check that this produces a value of type `a`.
2. During the execution of the `valNum` protocol, she:

   1. Chooses a type. Here she chooses the type that `idFrac` expects, namely `a`; this also happens to be the type her caller chose.
   2. Prove that `Num a` holds. This she can do, because her caller supplied a proof that `Fractional a`, and you can extract a proof of `Num a` from a proof of `Fractional a`.
   3. The implementer of `valNum` then provides a value of type `a`, as needed.

With all the details on the field, we can now try to zoom out and see the big picture. Both `applyIdNum` and `applyIdFrac` have the same type, namely `forall a. Fractional a => a`. So the implementer in both cases gets to assume that `a` is an instance of `Fractional`. But since all `Fractional` instances are `Num` instances, this means the implementer gets to assume both `Fractional` and `Num` apply. This makes it easy to use functions or values that assume either constraint in the implementation.

P.S. I repeatedly used the adverb "quietly" for choices of types needed during the `forall a. t` protocol. This is because Haskell tries very hard to hide these choices from the user. But you can make them explicit if you like with the `TypeApplications` extension; choosing type `t` in protocol `f` uses the syntax `f @t`. Instance proofs are still silently managed on your behalf, though.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is a lot to digest. I think your answer is the key to understanding all this. Can you explain where `forall a .` comes from all of a sudden? You just added it there. In particular, can there be anything *other than* `forall a .` there?

Comment: @haskellHQ Right, bare Haskell implicitly universally quantifies any free type variables -- that is, it implicitly puts `forall a b c. ...` in front of every type, mentioning all the variables in the type in the `forall`. While Haskell itself doesn't allow any other quantifiers in that position, there are languages that have a dual `exists` quantifier; and also `forall`'s can go in other places with some extensions, as in `Int -> (forall a. a -> a) -> Int` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

The type `a` in `baz :: Fractional a => a` is chosen by whoever calls `baz`. It is their responsibility to guarantee that their choice of `a` type is in the `Fractional` class. Since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, the type `a` must therefore be also a `Num`. Hence, `baz` can use both `foo` and `bar`.

In other words, because of the subclass relation, the signature

```
baz :: Fractional a => a
```

is essentially equivalent to

```
baz :: (Fractional a, Num a) => a
```

Your second example is actually of the same kind as the first one, it does not matter which one between `foo, bar` is the function and which one is the argument. You might also consider this:

```
foo :: Fractional a => a
foo = undefined

bar :: Num a => a
bar = undefined

baz :: Fractional a => a
baz = foo + bar -- Works
```

Comment: So the types of foo and bar unify and we can share the typeclass dictionary?

Comment: @Taren Yes, the types of `foo` and `bar` unify. No, GHC can't share the typeclass dictionary: it must supply a `Num` dictionary to one and a `Fractional` dictionary to the other. But the `Fractional` dictionary contains a `Num` dictionary, and that part at least is shared.

Answer (score 2):

> Works as expected because every `Fractional` is also a `Num`.

That is correct, but it's important to be precise about what this means. It means this: every **type** in the `Fractional` class is also in the `Num` class. It does *not* mean what someone with an OO or dynamic background might understand: “every **value** in a `Num` type is also in a `Fractional` type”. If this were the case, then your reasoning would make sense: then the `Num` value `bar` would be insufficiently general to be used in the `foo` function. 
...or actually it wouldn't be, because in an OO language the number hierarchy would work in the other direction – other languages usually allow you to cast any numerical value to a fractional one, but the other direction would in these languages incur round, which reasonably strongly typed ones won't automatically do!

In Haskell, you need to worry about none of this, because there are *never* any implicit type conversions. `bar` and `foo` work on the exact same type, that this type happens a variable `a` is secondary. Now, both `bar` and `foo` constrain this single type in different ways, but because it's the same type that's constrained you simply get a combination `(Num a, Fractional a)` of both constraints, which due to `Num a => Fractional a` is equivalent to `Fractional a` alone.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR:* it is not the case that `Num a => a` *is* a `Num` value, but rather it is a definition that *can* be a value of *any* type of `Num`, whatever that type is, specifically, as determined by each specific place where it is used.

---

We *define* it first, and we *use* it, later.

And if we've defined it *generally*, so that it can be used at many different specific types, we can use it later at many different use sites, which will each demand a specific type of value to be provided for it by our definition. As long as that specific type conforms to the type constraints as per the definition and the use site.

That's what being a *polymorphic **definition*** is all about.

It is *not* a polymorphic ***value***. *That* is a concept from the dynamic world, but ours is a static one. The types in Haskell are not decided at run time. They are known upfront.

---

Here's what happens:

```
> numfunc :: Num        a => a -> a; numfunc = undefined
> fraval  :: Fractional a => a;      fraval  = undefined

> :t numfunc fraval
numfunc fraval :: Fractional a => a
```

`numfunc` demands its argument to be in `Num`. `fraval` is a polymorphic definition, able to provide a datum of any type which is in `Fractional` as might be demanded of it by a particular use. Whatever it will be, since it's in `Fractional`, it's guaranteed to also be in `Num`, so it is acceptable by `numfunc`.

Since we now know that `a` is in `Fractional` (because of `fraval`), the type of the whole application is now known to be in `Fractional` as well (because of the type of `numfunc`).

Technically,

```
        fraval ::         Fractional a  => a         -- can provide any Fractional
numfunc        ::  Num               a  => a -> a    -- is able to process a Num
-------------------------------------------------
numfunc fraval :: (Num a, Fractional a) =>      a    -- can provide a Fractional
```

And `(Num a, Fractional a)` is simplified to the intersection of the type classes, i.e. just `Fractional a`.

This of course means that if there's nothing else in the rest of the code somewhere, further specifying the types, we'll get an ambiguous type error (unless some type defaulting kicks in). But there *might* be. For now this is acceptable, and has a type -- a *polymorphic* type, meaning, something else will have to further specify it somewhere in the rest of the code, at any particular use site where it appears. So for now, as a general polymorphic definition, this is perfectly acceptable.

---

Next,

```
> frafunc :: Fractional a => a -> a; frafunc = undefined
> numval  :: Num        a => a;      numval  = undefined

> :t frafunc numval
frafunc numval :: Fractional a => a
```

`frafunc` demands its type to be in `Fractional`. `numval` is able to provide a datum of whatever type is demanded of it as long as that type is in `Num`. So it's perfectly happy to oblige any demand for a `Fractional` type of value. Of course something else in the code will have to further specialize the types, but whatever. For now it's all good.

Technically,

```
        numval ::  Num               a  => a        -- can provide any Num
frafunc        ::         Fractional a  => a -> a   -- is able to process a Fractional
-------------------------------------------------
frafunc numval :: (Num a, Fractional a) =>      a   -- can provide any Fractional
```

---

<sub>(I post this answer because I think the simplest things can be a stumbling block for beginners, and these simplest things can be taken for granted without even noticing, by the experts. As the saying goes, we don't know who discovered *water*, but it sure wasn't a *fish*.)</sub>