# Why is this implementation invalid?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism

Let's say I have the following type signature:

```
someFunction :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b
```

With implementation:

```
someFunction x = (2 :: Int)
```

(Don't look in to it too far, it's just an example).

My understanding of the signature is that "`someFunction` takes an argument that is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass, and returns a value (that can be of a different type) that is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass". `Int` is an instance of `Eq`, so why does GHC get upset about this implementation?

The error makes it obvious enough:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘Int’
>      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>        the type signature for:
>          someFunction :: forall a b. (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b
> ```

I guess what I don't understand is the requirement that it work "forall" `b`. Any code using this function should only rely on the fact that `b` is an instance of `Eq`, right? In my head, the implementation does match the signature. What about my implementation is breaking the expectations of this  signature?

Comment: Because your signature says "I can return *any* `b`, as long as it is `Eq b`), but your implementation is clearly only returning `Int`s.

Comment: I suppose I'm misunderstanding the value of saying "i can return any b".

Comment: You might also like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820603/791604); there I describe types as a sort of two-player game, and I think it's a good way to summarize what's going on here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, your type signature, which is actually

```
forall a b. (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b
```

means that your function must be callable with *any* types `a` and `b`, as determined by the *call site*, as long as both are instances of `Eq`.

*It is not your function that decides what type to return.* It's your function's *use* that determines that.

So you should be able to write

```
    let { i :: Int; i = 1;
          n :: Integer; y :: Double;
          n = foo i;   -- foo :: Int -> Integer
          y = foo i    -- foo :: Int -> Double
        }
```

and as you can see, the only implementation for your function is *no* implementation:

```
foo _ = x where {x = x}
```

because you have no way to produce a value of *any* type that's demanded of you. That type can be anything, and you have no way of knowing anything about it.

---

By the way *other* typeclasses might actually allow you to define *something* here, like

```
foo :: (Enum a, Enum b, Bounded a, Bounded b) => a -> b 
foo a = snd . last $ zip [minBound .. a] (cycle [minBound ..])
```

I'm not saying it's a sensible definition, just that it is possible:

```
> foo () :: Bool
False

> foo True :: Int
-9223372036854775807

> foo (0 :: Int) :: Bool
Interrupted.
```

It is probably a common misconception for programmers coming from the more usual languages to think that `foo :: (Eq a) => a` means "I get to define `foo`  to return any type I want, as long as it is in `Eq`". It doesn't. :)

Comment: "It is not your function that decides what type to return. It's your function's use that determines that." - that statement helps a lot. Thanks. Getting my head around parametric polymorphism is a challenge sometimes.

Comment: @CameronBall I think it helps a lot visualizing the implicit type arguments. For instance, when we write `id True` GHC internally expands this to `id @Bool True`, where the `@Bool` part chooses the type `a` in `id :: forall a. a->a`. Essentially, polymorphic functions are functions with one or more "type" arguments, which need to be passed with the special `@T` syntax, or omitted so that type inference can fill them for us. As an exercise, you can try to add all the `@T`s on your own and see what's under the hood (turn on the `TypeApplications` extension first).