# type error when creating list from integral type

Tags: haskell, integer

I'm trying to implement a simple function: `totient`:

```hs
coprime :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
coprime a b = gcd a b == 1

totient :: Integral a => a -> a
totient m = length $ filter (coprime m) [1..m-1]

ghci> :load 99problems.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 99problems.hs, interpreted )

99problems.hs:250:13: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          totient :: forall a. Integral a => a -> a
        at 99problems.hs:249:12
    • In the expression: length $ filter (coprime m) [1 .. m - 1]
      In an equation for ‘totient’:
          totient m = length $ filter (coprime m) [1 .. m - 1]
    • Relevant bindings include
        m :: a (bound at 99problems.hs:250:9)
        totient :: a -> a (bound at 99problems.hs:250:1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I tried using stuff like `fromIntegral` or `toInteger` on `(m-1)` but none of it has worked. I'm not sure what I'm missing here... it seems like `Int` should be a type `Integral a => a`. What's going wrong?

Comment: the type of `length` is  `length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int`. But you are explicitly saying that `totient` should return an `Integral a`.

Comment: @JohEker I'm missing something, isn't `Int` an `Integral a` type? https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1270011

Comment: @johEker is right, your problem is in the `length` bit, which returns an `Int`. You can then convert that using `fromIntegral`

Comment: Yes, but your function has to type-check `forall a` in `Integral` , as you can also see from the error

Comment: @Lorenzo I'm still confused: `fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`. how does that make it typecheck if `fromIntegral` returns a `Num b => b` type when `totient` expects a `Integral a => a` type to be returned?

Comment: As the answer explains, `fromIntegral (Num b, Integral a) => A -> b` means that the caller (the `length` function) needs to provide it with any `Integral a`. `Int` is an `Integral` so this checks out. Then, `fromIntegral` returns a `Num b`, and the user (the `totient` function), chooses the type of this. In this case, you choose it to be a `Integral` in your type declaration.

Comment: Note that when you "choose" the returned type, you don't need to restrict it, in this case you could return `Num b` and it would still be valid.

Comment: You could also fix it by using `genericLength` (from `Data.List`) instead of `length`. It can be pretty annoying that `length` is monomorphic in its return type, it seems like a mistake in the initial design of the standard library which we can hope is changed in a future version.

Comment: @Lorenzo maybe I'm thinking about types incorrectly. What if `fromIntegral` returns a `Floating` or `Fractional` type? By my understanding, that would be a `Num` type, but it wouldn't be an `Integral` type, so it's weird why that would typecheck

Comment: But `fromIntegral` is returning a general `Num` type, and then you choose what you want it to be. You can leave as is, or you can "cast it" into a `Integral` like you're doing

Comment: @Lorenzo hmm... I think I got it. I was thinking in terms of values and not types. I don't know if this is the right way to phrase it, but an `Int` value can be "upcast" into an `Integral` value or `Num` value, but a `Num` type or `Integral` type can be "downcast" into an `Int` type; is that right?

Comment: Not quite. The essence is that `Num` and `Integral` are not types, they are typeclasses, which is like a set of types that have something in common, and with which you can so something. For example, `Eq` is a typeclass with those types that support and equality `(==)` operator. Similarly, `Num` is the typeclass of "numbers" (i.e. they support addition, multiplication and more). Have a look here and it might make it more clear http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses

Comment: @Lorenzo i'm sorry, now it makes less sense. the type returned by `fromIntegral` is in the `Num` typeclass, which is a type that supports some set X of properties. the typeclass `Integral` supports some set Y of properties, but X is a subset of Y, because to be a part of the typeclass `Integral` the type must also be a part of typeclass `Num`. then, why is returning a type in typeclass `Num` sufficient?

Comment: You got it the other way round. `Integral` is a subset of `Num`, so it supports all the properties `Num` does, plus some more, so X is a superset of Y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190972/discussion-between-zli-and-lorenzo).

Comment: @zli it's not letting me post this in the chatroom, so I'm doing it here instead: `fromIntegral` can return any type you want, provided it's an instance of `Num`.  And `totient` needs to be able to return any type you might want, that's an instance of `Integral`. But since `Integral` is a subclass of `Num` this is no problem at all. Basically the type signature of `totient` places more restrictions on which types `fromIntegral` is allowed to return.

Comment: It wouldn't work the other way round - if `totient` had a more general return type such as any `Eq` instance - because then you might use the result of `totient` on a type (say `String`) which is in `Eq` but not `Num`. This obviously wouldn't work because `fromIntegral` can't return a `String` - and Haskell will tell you this by not allowing `totient` to typecheck. In other words the return type of `totient` needs to be at least restrictive as that of `fromIntegral`, to avoid this. Being more restrictive, as you are doing, can't lead to any such problem.

Comment: thanks @RobinZigmond. i don't know why i'm having such a hard time wrapping my head around this. `totient` returns an instance from `Integral` typeclass, let's say the `Integral` typeclass supports functions A and B. `fromIntegral` returns an instance from `Num` typeclass, let's say the `Num` typeclass only supports function A. as a caller of `totient` I want to use function B on the result (which I expect to be an instance from `Integral` typeclass). however, since `fromIntegral` returns an instance of the `Num` typeclass, it only guarantees that I can use function A on the result.

Comment: to me that seems pretty dangerous, and I don't understand why we're able to just "coerce" types to fit the type signature when it doesn't seem like the guarantee that we can use it as we want exists

Comment: `fromIntegral`, in isolation, does indeed return an instance of `Num`, which in your schematic representation supports function `A` but not necessarily `B`. But what you're overlooking is that you're not using it in isolation, your type signature for `totient` tells Haskell that it will return an instance of `Integral`, and therefore also have access to `B`. It is `totient` here, via its type signature that provides the guarantees to any function which uses its result. While `fromIntegral` doesn't have as many guarantees, that doesn't matter, they're provided by the context.

Comment: to put it another way, `fromIntegral` is one of several "strange" functions in Haskell in that it is polymorphic in its return type. Given the same input (of the same type), it can actually return results of different types - and the return type either needs to be given explicitly, or inferred from the context. The latter is what happens here - or at least the return type is restricted somewhat by the context. In isolation it could be any instance of `Num`, its use in `totient` further restricts it to an instance of `Integral`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond thanks so much for patiently explaining. i don't know if i've completely grokked it, but i think i'm just starting to accept the weirdness. maybe i should sleep on it or come back 10 years later when i'm more competent of a haskell developer (:

Comment: just to be sure, adding the `fromIntegral` as `totient m = fromIntegral $ length $ filter ...` would also solve your problem, as would changing the signature to `... -> Int` instead (since `length` returns an `Int`). [*It is not your function that decides what type to return*. It's your function's *use* that determines that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52925066/849891).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `Integral a => a -> a` says:

1. Caller gets to choose a type `a`.
2. Caller must prove that `a` is an instance of `Integral`.
3. Caller must provide a value of type `a`.
4. Implementer produces another value of type `a`.

However, in this case, the implementer has produced an `Int`. Any time the caller chooses `a` to be an instance of `Integral` that is not `Int`, this will not match the caller's type.