# Haskell: Understanding type conversion mechanics by `fromIntegral`

Tags: haskell, types

### Understanding type conversion by `fromIntegral`

So, I have been running into a lot of type conversion errors lately. This brought me to the use of `fromIntegral`, though I am quite puzzled on the way it works.

```
minimalExample :: Integer -> Integer
minimalExample a = truncate y
    where
        x = fromIntegral (a + 10)
        y = x - 12 * (x / 13)
```

Note how I had to use `fromIntegral` to make sure `x` is of the right type for the `(/)` operator. It wouldn't have worked if `x` was an Integral type. A typecheck for the functions in GHCI gives me this info:

```
Prelude> :t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b

Prelude> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

Obviously `fromIntegral` converts an `Int`/`Integer` into some `Num` class type (which one? I have no idea). The division infix operator expects two Fractionals as input. Now take a look at [this graphic](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Base-classes.svg/788px-Base-classes.svg.png), which summarizes the standard type-class-relations in Haskell.

`Num` is above `Fractional`, which means not every `Num`-Type is a `Fractional`. So why does `(/)` accept a generic `Num`-type as an argument?

I assume it is because `fromIntegral` doesn't really convert to a `Num` (those aren't even instantiable, are they? Only inheritable by concrete types), but rather it converts directly to a `Double` or a `Float`.

If so, which one does it actually convert to? And why doesn't it actually list that concrete type in its definition, instead of the fuzzy and generic `Num` class type?

Comment: "So why does (/) accept a generic Num-type as an argument?" It doesn't. It only accepts an instance of `Fractional`. But since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num`, and `fromIntegral` can produce any `Num`, `fromIntegral` can also produce a `Fractional` - as it has to in order to be used with `(/)`. As for why the functions don't list a concrete type in their definition, it's because that would unnecessarily restrict their use - but being polymorphic they can be used in more situations.

Comment: PS there was much discussion of a similar point recently in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436571/type-error-when-creating-list-from-integral-type)

Comment: "Obviously fromIntegral converts an Int/Integer into some Num class type (which one? I have no idea)." I like to think of it as a nondeterministic function that converts its argument into a value of *all* types with a `Num` instance. The values exist in a superposition until you "observe" the value of the requested type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fromIntegral` doesn't convert to some vague unknowable `Num` type. It converts to the one that's demanded of it. That is, `fromIntegral` doesn't choose its own result type; the caller does. So

```
fromIntegral :: Int -> Integer
fromIntegral :: Int -> Word
fromIntegral :: Integer -> Double
```

Etc. In this case, the type checker infers

```
minimalExample :: Integer -> Integer
minimalExample a = truncate y
  where
    x, y :: Fractional n => n
    x = fromIntegral (a + 10)
    y = x - 12 * (x / 13)
```

because `(/)` demands a `Fractional` type.

Then the defaulting mechanism kicks in to fix `n`:

```
minimalExample :: Integer -> Integer
minimalExample a = truncate y
  where
    x, y :: Double
    x = fromIntegral (a + 10)
    y = x - 12 * (x / 13)
```

You might expect this, instead, to turn out

```
minimalExample :: Integer -> Integer
minimalExample a = truncate (y :: Double)
  where
    x, y :: Fractional n => n
    x = fromIntegral (a + 10)
    y = x - 12 * (x / 13)
```

I certainly did! But it does not. The dreaded monomorphism restriction kicks in and forces `x` and `y` to be monomorphic in the constrained type `n`, because they are not (syntactically) functions. Yeah, the monomorphism restriction is weird.