# Why is `succ i` valid where `i :: Num a => a` (and not an `Enum a`)?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, ghci

This seems to apply to both GHCi and GHC. I'll show an example with GHCi first.

Given `i` type has been inferred as follows:

```
Prelude> i = 1
Prelude> :t i
i :: Num p => p
```

Given that `succ` is a function defined on `Enum`:

```
Prelude> :i Enum
class Enum a where
  succ :: a -> a
  pred :: a -> a
  -- …OMITTED…
```

and that `Num` is not a 'subclass' (if I can use that term) of `Enum`:

```
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
-- …OMITTED…
```

why `succ i` does not return an error?

```
Prelude> succ i
2 -- works, no error
```

I would expect `:type i` to be inferred to something like:

```
Prelude> i = 1
Prelude> :type i
i :: (Enum p, Num p) => p
```

*(I'm using 'GHC v. 8.6.3')*

**ADDITION:**

After reading @RobinZigmond comment and @AlexeyRomanov answer I have noticed that `1` could be interpreted as one of many types and one of many classes.
Thanks to @AlexeyRomanov answer I understand much more about the defaulting-rules used to decide what type to use for ambiguous expressions.

However I don't feel that Alexey answer addresses exactly my question. My question is about the type of `i`. It's not about the type of `succ i`.

It's about the mismatch between `succ` argument type (an `Enum a`) and the apparent type of `i` (a `Num a`).

I'm now starting to realise that my question must stem from a wrong assumption: 'that once `i` is inferred to be `i :: Num a => a`, then `i` can be *nothing else*'. Hence I was puzzled to see `succ i` was evaluated without errors.

GHC also seems to be inferring `Enum a` in addition to what was explicitly declared.

```
x :: Num a => a
x = 1
y = succ x -- works
```

However it is not adding `Enum a` when the type variable appears as a function:

```
my_succ :: Num a => a -> a
my_succ z = succ z -- fails compilation
```

To me it seems that the type constraints attached to a function are stricter to the ones applied to a variable.

GHC is saying `my_succ :: forall a. Num a => a -> a` and given 
`forall a` doesn't appear in the type-signature of neither `i` nor `x` I thought that meant GHC is not going to infer any more classes for `my_succ` types.

But this seems again wrong: I've checked this idea with the following (first time I type RankNTypes) and apparently GHC still infers `Enum a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

x :: forall a. Num a => a
x = 1
y = succ x
```

So it seems that inference rules for functions are stricter than the ones for variables?

Comment: You've defined `i` as `1`, which can be a member of any type of class `Num`. When you use `succ`, that further constrains the type to be of class `Enum`. But this isn't a problem since there are several types in both classes, and `2` represents the result in each of them.

Comment: @RobinZigmond That's true (for standard types; you could define your own which worked differently), but not at all the reason GHCi gives `2` as the answer.

Comment: You might also like: [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820603/791604). In fact I'm tempted to mark this one as a duplicate. In short, the user of `i` gets to choose which instance of `Num` it wants, and in particular the user can choose a type which also has an `Enum` instance.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's interesting! They seem indeed related, but I'm not sure we can call them duplicates: I'm still digesting what's being said so far.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `succ i`'s type is inferred as you expect:

```
Prelude> :t succ i
succ i :: (Enum a, Num a) => a
```

This type is ambiguous, but it satisfies the conditions in [the defaulting rules](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#type-defaulting-in-ghci) for GHCi:

> Find all the unsolved constraints. Then:
>
> - Find those that are of form `(C a)` where `a` is a type variable, and partition those constraints into groups that share a common type variable `a`.

In this case, there's only one group: `(Enum a, Num a)`.

> - Keep only the groups in which at least one of the classes is an interactive class (defined below).

This group is kept, because `Num` is an interactive class.

> - Now, for each remaining group G, try each type `ty` from the default-type list in turn; if setting `a = ty` would allow the constraints in G to be completely solved. If so, default `a` to `ty`.
> - The unit type `()` and the list type `[]` are added to the start of the standard list of types which are tried when doing type defaulting.

The default default-type list (sic) is (with the additions from the last clause) `default ((), [], Integer, Double)`.

So when you do `Prelude> succ i` to actually evaluate this expression (note `:t` doesn't evaluate the expression it gets), `a` is set to `Integer` (first of this list satisfying the constraints), and the result is printed as `2`.

You can see it's the reason by changing the default:

```
Prelude> default (Double)
Prelude> succ 1
2.0
```

For the updated question:

> I'm now starting to realise that my question must stem from a wrong assumption: 'that once `i` is inferred to be `i :: Num a => a`, then `i` can be nothing else'. Hence I was puzzled to see `succ i` was evaluated without errors.

`i` can be nothing *else* (i.e. nothing that doesn't fit this type), but it can be used with less general (more specific) types: `Integer`, `Int`. Even with many of them in an expression at once:

```
Prelude> (i :: Double) ^ (i :: Integer)
1.0
```

And these uses don't affect the type of `i` itself: it's already defined and its type fixed. OK so far?

Well, adding constraints also makes the type more specific, so `(Num a, Enum a) => a` is more specific than `(Num a) => a`:

```
Prelude> i :: (Num a, Enum a) => a
1
```

Because of course any type `a` that satisfies both constraints in `(Num a, Enum a)` satisfies just `Num a`.

> However it is not adding `Enum a` when the type variable appears as a function:

That's because you specified a signature which doesn't allow it to. If you don't give a signature, there's no reason to infer `Num` constraint. But e.g.

```
Prelude> f x = succ x + 1
```

will infer the type with both constraints:

```
Prelude> :t f
f :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> a
```

> So it seems that inference rules for functions are stricter than the ones for variables?

It's actually the other way around due to the [monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.5.5) (not in GHCi, by default). You've actually been a bit lucky not to run into it here, but the answer is already long enough. Searching for the term should give you explanations.

> GHC is saying `my_succ :: forall a. Num a => a -> a` and given `forall a` doesn't appear in the type-signature of neither `i` nor `x`.

That's a red herring. I am not sure why it's shown in one case and not the other, but all of them have that `forall a` behind the scenes:

> > [Haskell type signatures are implicitly quantified.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ExplicitForAll) When the language option `ExplicitForAll` is used, the keyword `forall` allows us to say exactly what this means. For example:
> >
> > ```
> > g :: b -> b
> > ```
> >
> > means this:
> >
> > ```
> > g :: forall b. (b -> b)
> > ```

(Also, you just need `ExplicitForAll` and not `RankNTypes` to write down `forall a. Num a => a`.)

Comment: In GHCi, `ExtendedDefaultRules` is enabled by default, so I'm pretty sure the "standard class" condition is dropped. It would be relevant by default in compiled code.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned and linked the extended rules in the answer. But looking at them at first, I thought they delegated more to the Report than they actually do (it was already 1 AM here :)), so decided to quote it instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: This helped me understand more about what's going on behind the scenes. But it doesn't seem to address the core of my question. So I'm not yet accepting it. I've tried to clarify my question by adding more to it. Thanks

Comment: The root of my bewilderment is that I interpreted `i :: Num a => a` as all that is known about `i` from that point onward. In Java terms, I saw `i` as being given an `INumber` interface… how could the compiler know, I thought, that the underlying instance could also be a `Enumerable` after that point? But, from what I see and what's being said, I guess that GHCi knows what's the thing underlying `i :: Num a => a`, so it knows it can also be `Enum a`, and `Integer` and `Double`…
This I haven't digested this yet, TBH. I reckon I've hit a quite peculiar case and should look at it again later.

Comment: @basilikode In Java terms, it's closer to `<A extends Number> A i()` than `Number i()`. It's the caller who picks `a`/`A`, and can pick `Integer` or `Double`. Or call this method from another generic method `<A extends Number & Enumerable> A j() { return <A> i().succ(); }`.