# Difference between forall quantifier inside a constructor and outside a constructor

Tags: haskell

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Data.Proxy

data Foo = FooA | FooB

class Bar (a :: k) where
    bar :: Proxy a -> Int

instance Bar FooA where
    bar _ = 1

instance Bar FooB where
    bar _ = 2

foo1 :: forall (a :: Foo). Proxy a -> (Bar a => Proxy a)
foo1 p = p

data BarProxy = BarProxy (forall a. Bar a => Proxy a)

foo2 :: forall (a :: Foo). Proxy a -> BarProxy
foo2 p = BarProxy (foo1 p)

main = print "Hello World"
```

In this code:

1. Doesn't `foo1`, given any `Proxy a` where `a` is of kind `Foo`, return a `Proxy a` such that `a` has an instance of `Bar`?
2. Doesn't `BarProxy` constructor accept any `Proxy a`, where `a` has an instance of `Bar`? How is it different from `data BarProxy = forall a. BarProxy (Bar a => Proxy a)`?
3. Why does `foo2 p = BarProxy (foo1 p)` fail with the below error?

```hs
Test6.hs:27:20: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘a’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall (a1 :: Foo). Bar a1 => Proxy a1
        at Test6.hs:27:10-26
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foo2 :: forall (a :: Foo). Proxy a -> BarProxy
        at Test6.hs:26:1-46
      Expected type: Proxy a1
        Actual type: Proxy a
    • In the first argument of ‘BarProxy’, namely ‘(foo1 p)’
      In the expression: BarProxy (foo1 p)
      In an equation for ‘foo2’: foo2 p = BarProxy (foo1 p)
    • Relevant bindings include
        p :: Proxy a (bound at Test6.hs:27:6)
        foo2 :: Proxy a -> BarProxy (bound at Test6.hs:27:1)
   |
27 | foo2 p = BarProxy (foo1 p)
   |                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Not sure about the other questions, but you are correct for (2); for (3), it fails because it accepts a `Proxy a`, where `a` is an instance of `Foo`, but the `BarProxy` constructor requires an `a` which is an instance of `Bar` (I think). Also, I must say I’ve never seen the syntax `(Bar a => Proxy a)` before, where `a` isn’t quantified with a `forall`; where did you see it?

Comment: @bradrn, I haven't seen it anywhere else. I only recently learned that, `BarProxy (forall a. Bar a => Proxy a)` is internally `BarProxy (<Bar instance for a>, Proxy a)`, and `foobar :: Bar a => Proxy a -> Int` is `foobar :: <Bar instance> -> Proxy a -> Int`. I wanted to learn how the instances are passed around in the return  position.

Comment: You might also my description of `forall` in terms of a game-like semantics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821578/791604).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. My understanding is that the signature of `foo1` is the same as `forall (a :: Foo). Bar a => Proxy a -> Proxy a` (though I couldn't find any document).
   In ghci, `:t foo1` gives `foo1 :: Bar a => Proxy a -> Proxy a`.
   Given any `Proxy a` where `a` is of kind `Foo` and an instance of `Bar`, it returns `Proxy a`.
2. No. The constructor `BarProxy` has rank-2 polymorphic type `(forall a. Bar a => Proxy a) -> BarProxy`.
   This means that an argument `p` can be passed to `BarProxy` only if
   `p` has the type `Proxy a` for *all* type `a` which is an instance of `Bar`.
   If you want existentially quantified one, you may write

   ```
   data BarProxy = forall a. Bar a => BarProxy (Proxy a)
   ```

   or

   ```
   data BarProxy where
     BarProxy :: forall a. Bar a => Proxy a -> BarProxy
   ```

   with `-XGADTs` enabled.

   Let us call
    `BarProxy` of type `forall a. Bar a => Proxy a -> BarProxy` *existential* `BarProxy` and
    that of type `(forall a. Bar a => Proxy a) -> BarProxy` *universal* `BarProxy`.
   For existential one, the argument `p` should have type *either* `Proxy FooA` *or* `Proxy FooB` (existentially quantified over `{a | a is an instance of Bar} = {FooA,FooB}`).
   For universal one, on the other hand, `p` should have type *both* `Proxy FooA` *and* `Proxy FooB` (universally quantified over the same set).
   Let us consider three proxies below.

   ```
   proxyFooA :: Proxy FooA
   proxyFooA = Proxy

   proxyFooB :: Proxy FooB
   proxyFooB = Proxy

   proxyPoly :: forall a. Proxy a
   proxyPoly = Proxy
   ```

   Existential `BarProxy` accepts any of the three while universal one accepts only `proxyPoly`.
3. `foo2 p = BarProxy (foo1 p)` compiles for existential `BarProxy`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the difference between `BarProxy :: forall a. Bar a => Proxy a -> BarProxy` and `BarProxy :: (forall a. Bar a => Proxy a) -> BarProxy`?

"This means that an argument p can be passed to BarProxy only if p has the type Proxy a for any type a which is an instance of Bar". Here also a is existentially qualified right?

Comment: In the former case, `p` should have type __either__ `Proxy FooA` __or__ `Proxy FooB` (existentially quantified over `{FooA, FooB}`). In the latter case, __both__ `Proxy FooA` __and__ `Proxy FooB` (universally quantified over the same set).

Comment: Let `proxyFooA :: Proxy FooA`, `proxyFooB :: Proxy FooB`, and `proxyPoly :: forall a. Proxy a`. Existential `BarProxy` accepts any of the three while Universal `BarProxy` accepts only `proxyPoly`.

Comment: Okay. And can `proxyPoly` have any value other than `undefined`?

Comment: The constructor `Proxy` also has that type.

Comment: The misunderstanding of `BarProxy :: forall a. Bar a => Proxy a -> BarProxy` and `BarProxy :: (forall a. Bar a => Proxy a) -> BarProxy` was from where my question actually came. Could you please add these information to the answer too?

Comment: changing the type of `BarProxy` to `forall a. Bar a => Proxy a -> BarProxy` fixed the error. So you have answered the 3rd point too :)

Comment: I can verify your first point. In ghci, `:t foo1` gives `foo1 :: Bar a => Proxy a -> Proxy a`.