# Haskell type with tuples

Tags: list, haskell, types, tuples

This question is focused specifically on list of tuples.

I was using `sort` to sort a list of tuples; at first I thought ghci would raise an error or something, but instead I received a sorted list based on the first element of my tuple!

```
Prelude Data.List> :t sort
sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
Prelude Data.List> sort [3,1,2]
[1,2,3]
Prelude Data.List> sort [(3,'c'), (1,'a'),(2,'b')]
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]
Prelude Data.List> sort [(3,'c',1), (1,'a',2),(2,'b',3)]
[(1,'a',2),(2,'b',3),(3,'c',1)]
```

The same happens to functions with similar behaviors like `minimum` but not to those like `any`. So I guess this is a syntax sugar (Haskell always has some syntaxes that I have no idea about), but I'm not sure if this applies to other `(Foldable t, Ord a) => t a` types, nor if this is a more generic feature.

How does Haskell treat a tuple of type `(a,b)` so that `f :: ([a] -> [c])` can be apply to  `l :: [(a, b)]`? And does this way apply to other data structures or this is more like list-only?

Comment: Tuples are lexicographically `Ord`ered: the first components is compared first. On a tie, the second components are compared, And so on. So a list of tuples is a list of ordered elements, and can be sorted.

Comment: You might like my discussion of how to read types as two-player games in [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821578/791604). In the terms used in that answer: the caller of `sort :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> [a]` chooses `a` to be `(Int, Char)`, then provides evidence that `(Int, Char)` is an instance of `Ord`. Type variables can be instantiated to be *any* (monomorphic) type, including `Int` and tuples and lists and trees and `Bool`s and whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

There isn't any magic here. That is because functions you have considered are `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` and `minimum :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> a`. Here you can see context `Ord a`, and in your case this `a` is a tuple `(a, b)`. There is instance for tuple `(Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (a, b)`. That's why you can execute `(1,3) < (2,4)`. That's why it's working. And this functions will work with, for example, list of `Maybe a`.

`any` has type `Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`, and it's can work with list of tuples. For example, like so:

```hs
any ((== 1) . fst) [(1,3), (2,4), (3,5)]
```

But not so:

```hs
any (== 1) [(1,3), (2,4), (3,5)]
```