# Overloaded / Polymorphic Functions with different types

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and came into an unanswered question:

From the lesson I'm following:

```
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

> For any numeric type `a`, (+) takes 2 values of type `a` and returns a value of type `a`.

As per the examples:

```
1 + 1
-- 2 # type a is Int
3.0 + 4.0
-- 7.0 type a is Float
'a' + 'b' 
-- Type Error: Char is not a Numeric type
```

This makes perfect sense, but i end up not understanding what goes on in the background, when:

```
1 + 3.0
```

Is the Type Inference system auto casting my Int to Float because it knows it will return Float?

Comment: You might also like [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820603/791604).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should investigate these sorts of questions in ghci.  It's an invaluable learning resource:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> :t 1
1 :: Num p => p
ghci> :t 3.0
3.0 :: Fractional p => p
ghci> :t 1 + 3.0
1 + 3.0 :: Fractional a => a
```

First lesson: Numeric literals are polymorphic. `1` isn't an `Int`, it's polymorphic.  It can be any instance of `Num` that is necessary for the code to compile. `3.0` isn't a `Float`, it's any instance of `Fractional` that is necessary for the code to compile. (The difference being the decimal in the literal - it restricts the types allowed.)

Second Lesson: when you combine things into an expression, types get unified. When you unify `Num` and `Fractional` constraints, you get a `Fractional` constraint. This is because `Fractional` is defined to require all instances of it also be instances of `Num`.

For a bit more, let's turn on warnings and see what additional information they provide.

```
ghci> :set -Wall
ghci> 1

<interactive>:5:1: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Integer’
        (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at <interactive>:5:1
        (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’ at <interactive>:5:1
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
1
ghci> 1 + 3.0

<interactive>:6:1: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraints to type ‘Double’
        (Show a0) arising from a use of ‘print’ at <interactive>:6:1-7
        (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’ at <interactive>:6:1-7
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
4.0
```

When printing a value, ghci requires the type have a `Show` instance. Fortunately, that isn't too important of a detail here, but it's why the defaulting warnings refer to `Show`.

The lessons to observe here are that the default type for something with a `Num` instance if inference doesn't require something more specific is `Integer`, not `Int`.  The default type for something with a `Fractional` instance if inference doesn't require something more specific is `Double`, not `Float`. (`Float` is basically never used. Forget it exists.)

So when inference runs, the expression `1 + 3.0` is inferred to have the type `Fractional a => a`. In the absence of further requirements on the type, defaulting kicks in and says "`a` is `Double`". Then that information flows back through the `(+)` to its arguments and requires each of them to also be `Double`. Fortunately, each argument is a polymorphic literal that can take the type `Double`. Type checking succeeds, instances are chosen, addition happens, the result is printed.

It's very important to this process that numeric literals are polymorphic. Haskell has no implicit conversions between any pair of types. Especially not numeric types. If you want to actually *convert* values from one type to another, you must call a function that does the conversion you desire. (`fromIntegral`, `round`, `floor`, `ceiling`, and `realToFrac` are the most common numeric conversion functions.) But when the values are polymorphic, it means inference can pick a matching type without needing a conversion.

Comment: what a great response. It's not gonna be easy to keep track of all these details,  especially coming from other paradygms, but you broke it down perfectly and gave me a great set of tools also

Comment: Great answer! I've just recently started HS and this put just pieces of information I gathered earlier in place.