# Why can't I match type Int with type a

Tags: haskell

Haskell Noob here.

An oversimplified case of what I'm trying to do here:

```hs
test :: Int -> a
test i = i -- Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Int’. ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by ...
```

I don't quite understand why this wouldn't work. I mean, `Int` is surely included in something of type `a`.

What I was really trying to achieve is this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data EnumType = Enum1 | Enum2 | Enum3

data MyType (a :: EnumType) where
  Type1 :: Int -> MyType 'Enum1
  Type2 :: String -> MyType 'Enum2
  Type3 :: Bool -> MyType 'Enum3

myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType 'Enum1 -> MyType any
myFunc Enum1 t = t -- Can't match type `any` with `Enum1`. any is a rigid type variable bound by ...
myFunc Enum2 _ = Type2 "hi"
myFunc Enum3 _ = Type3 True
```

What is going on here? Is there a way to work around this or is it just something you can't do?

Comment: Your function promises that for *any* `a`, it can convert an `Int` to that `a`, so if you decide that `a` is a `Char`, then your function should still be able to convert the `Int` to a `Char`.

Comment: This is not like Java for example where a return type of `object` promises that the output will be a subclass of object. But where one can not decide by calling the function what that object will be.

Comment: You might like my answer to [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821578/791604). In short: it is the caller, not the implementer, of `test` that is allowed to choose what monomorphic value to specialize `a` to; and they might choose something that isn't `Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the GADT function you want to write, the standard technique is to use singletons. The problem is that values of type `EnumType` are value-level things, but you want to inform the type system of something. So you need a way to connect *types* of *kind* `EnumType` with *values* of *type* `EnumType` (which itself has kind `Type`). That's impossible, so we cheat: we connect types `x` of kind `EnumType` with values of a new type, `SEnumType x`, such that the value uniquely determines `x`. Here's how it looks:

```
data SEnumType a where
    SEnum1 :: SEnumType Enum1
    SEnum2 :: SEnumType Enum2
    SEnum3 :: SEnumType Enum3

myFunc :: SEnumType a -> MyType Enum1 -> MyType a
myFunc SEnum1 t = t
myFunc SEnum2 _ = Type2 "hi"
myFunc SEnum3 _ = Type3 True
```

Now the `a` in the return type `MyType a` isn't just fabricated out of thin air; it is constrained to be equal to the incoming `a` from `SEnumType`, and pattern matching on which `SEnumType` it is lets you observe whether `a` is `Enum1`, `Enum2`, or `Enum3`.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way to work around this or is it just something you can't do?

I'm afraid that it's just "something you can't do". The reason is simple to explain.

When you write a type signature like (to take your first, simpler example)

```
test :: Int -> a
```

or, to write it the more literal, expanded form

```
test :: forall a. Int -> a
```

You are saying that literally, "for all `a`", this function can take an Int and return a value of type `a`. This is important, because calling code has to believe this type signature and therefore be able to do something like this (this isn't realistic code, but imagine a case where you feed the result of `test 2` to a function that requires a `Char` or one of those other types):

```
test 2 :: Char
test 2 :: [Int]
test 2 :: (Double, [Char])
```

and so on. Clearly your function can't work with any of these examples - but it *has to* be able to work with *any* of them if you give it this type signature. Your code, quite simply, does not fit that type signature. (And nor could any, unless you "cheat" by having eg `test x = undefined`.)

This shouldn't be a problem though - the compiler is simply protecting you from a mistake, because I'm sure you realise that your code cannot satisfy this type signature. To take your "real" example:

```
myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType Enum1 -> MyType any
```

although this produces a compilation error, your code in the function is likely correct, and the problem is the type signature. If you replace it with

```
myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType Enum1 -> MyType Enum1
```

then it will compile (barring any further errors, which I've not checked it for), and presumably do what you want. It doesn't look like you actually want to be able to call `myFunc` and have it produce, say, a `MyType Int`. (If by any chance you do, I'd suggest you ask a separate question where you elaborate on what you actually need here.)

Answer (score 6):

As was already said, your signature expresses a universal type

```
myFunc :: ∀ a . EnumType -> MyType 'Enum1 -> MyType a
```

whereas what you're actually trying to express is an *existential* type

```
myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType 'Enum1 -> (∃ a . MyType a)
```

Haskell doesn't have a feature quite like that, but it does have some way to achieve essentially the same thing.

1. Both GADTs and the `ExistentialTypes` extension allow expressing existentials, but you need to define a separate type for them.

   ```
   data MyDynType where
     MyDynWrap :: MyType a -> MyDynType

   myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType 'Enum1 -> MyDynType
   myFunc Enum1 t = MyDynWrap t
   myFunc Enum2 _ = MyDynWrap $ Type2 "hi"
   myFunc Enum3 _ = MyDynWrap $ Type3 True
   ```
2. Maybe you don't even need a separate type, but can simply modify `MyType` to be “dynamic” in the first place.

   ```
   data MyType = Type1 Int | Type2 String | Type3 Bool

   myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType -> MyType
   myFunc Enum1 (Type1 i) = Type1 i
   myFunc Enum2 _ = Type2 "hi"
   myFunc Enum3 _ = Type3 True
   ```
3. existentials can be emulated at the spot, anonymously, by unwrapping a layer of continuation-passing style and then using the dual universal quantifier via the RankNTypes extension.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

   data MyType (a :: EnumType) where ... -- as original

   myFunc :: EnumType -> MyType 'Enum1 -> (∀ a . MyType a -> r) -> r
   myFunc Enum1 t q = q t
   myFunc Enum2 _ q = q (Type2 "hi")
   myFunc Enum3 _ q = q (Type3 True)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

the GADT function you want to write, the standard technique is to use singletons. The problem is that values of type EnumType are ...