# Every Lens' is a Traversal'... how?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, haskell-lens

[Control.Lens.Tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-tutorial-1.0.4/docs/Control-Lens-Tutorial.html#:%7E:text=exactly%20one%20value.-,Like,-Lens%27%2C) says:

> ```
> type Traversal' a b = forall f . Applicative f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a) 
> type Lens'      a b = forall f . Functor     f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
> ```
>
> Notice that the only difference between a Lens' and a Traversal' is the type class constraint. A Lens' has a Functor constraint and Traversal' has an Applicative constraint. This means that any Lens' is automatically also a valid Traversal' (since Functor is a superclass of Applicative).

I simply don't follow the logical sequence here. We know that every `Applicative` is a `Functor`. From this, should it not follow, if at all, that every `Traversal'` is a `Lens'`? The tutorial however reaches the converse conclusion.

Comment: You might also like [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820603/791604).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `Lens'` works for *all* functors, which includes all applicative functors, so if a function `g` is a `Lens'`, then `g` is also a `Traversal'`.

A `Traversal'` works for all applicative functors, but not necessarily all functors. So if a function `h` is a `Traversal'`, it is not necessarily a `Lens'`.

(I'm not the one to describe this formally, but to me at least, it looks like the types are "contravariant" in their constraints. `Lens'` is a subtype of `Traversal'` precisely *because* `Functor` is a superclass of `Applicative`.)

Comment: Another way of putting it that may help: If a Lens *were* a Functor and a Traversal *were* an Applicative, the logic in the question would make sense. But rather, a Lens is something that takes a Functor as an argument, while a Traversal takes an Applicative as an argument. So the more general item is the one with the more general argument.

Comment: Honestly, I'd love if someone would (accurately) describe how the `forall f` works. I assume a good answer would explain the difference between `Applicative f => ...` and `forall f . Applicative f => ...`. (I'm correct in assuming this is a necessary `forall`, and not just an explicit `forall`, right?)

Comment: (Either in a new answer, or editing this one; I'm fine with changing this to a community wiki in the latter case.)

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the names `f` and `g` from (probably just using the common function monikers?), but it's not immediately clear that you are not referring to the type variable `f` from the definitions in the question.

Comment: @chepner You might like my answer at [Why can a Num act like a Fractional?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42821578/791604), which attempts to accurately describe how `forall` works and how it interacts with type classes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not usually a fan of cute "real-world entity" analogies, but this matter probably does become clearer by considering the following example:

```
class Animal a where feed :: a -> ArmouredGlove -> IO String

instance Animal Cat where feed _ _ = print "Miaow"
instance Animal Dog where feed _ _ = print "Woof"
instance Animal Lion where feed _ _ = print "Rwaaar"

class Animal a => Pet a where cuddle :: a -> UnprotectedHand -> IO String

instance Pet Cat where cuddle _ _ = print "Purr"
instance Pet Dog where cuddle _ _ = print "Yawn"

type PetOwner = ∀ a . Pet a => a -> IO String
type ZooWarden = ∀ a . Animal a => a -> IO String

peter :: PetOwner
peter = \pet -> cuddle pet peter'sHand

zoey :: ZooWarden
zoey = \animal -> feed animal zoey'sGlove
```

Here, `ZooWarden` is a subtype of `PetOwner`. Zoey can handle a pet just fine, she can feed any dog as well as lions. But Peter does not have such qualification, he can *only* handle harmless pets. So, precisely because he is restricted to a more specific class of animals, he himself is member of a more general type of person than the specialised zoo warden.

Comment: Why are `Peter'sHand` and `Zoey'sGlove` types here? Shouldn't they be concrete instances of `UnprotectedHand` and `ArmouredGlove`?

Comment: @A.R. they're _constructors_. But yeah, maybe that doesn't make so much sense, I'm making them simple values.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dictionary-passing view of type classes. This is how type classes are actually implemented in GHC.

### Background

In this form, type classes like `Functor` and `Applicative` look something like this:

```
data Functor f =
  MkFunctor
    { fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b }

data Applicative f =
  MkApplicative
    { appFunctor :: Functor f
    , pure :: a -> f a
    , (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    }
```

Instances are values of those types, for example like this:

```
listFunctor :: Functor []
listFunctor =
  MkFunctor
    { fmap = map }
```

### Lenses and traversals

Now, let's say we have a lens `someLens :: Lens' A B` and we want to turn it into a traversal. Let's expand the type synonym and use dictionary passing:

```
someLens :: Functor f -> (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
```

In this style, you might use it with the list functor like this `someLens listFunctor`.

We want a traversal `someTraversal :: Traversal' A B`. When we implement this, we will need to provide `someLens` with a `Functor f` value. But we already have an `Applicative f` value:

```
someTraversal :: Applicative f -> (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)
someTraversal applicativeDict = someLens (appFunctor applicativeDict)
```

We can just use the field accessor that gets the `Functor` implementation for the `Applicative` instance we were given, and we have a `Traversal`. The field accessor has type `appFunctor :: Applicative f -> Functor f`.